# How to determine what file called a c++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a C++ program for a Windows 7 user which will be the default program called when she double-clicks certain files (.ora files) and I need to know how I can essentially pass in to the program the file name [including path] that she is trying to open.  Since the program won't be running at the time of file selection, I can't use mouse events to cheat...  How can I have a Win32 platform C++ program figure out what file called it?

thanks,
CCJ

Comment: Google for `windows file associations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When double-clicking a file results in opening an executable, the path and name of the file are passed as the first command line argument.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc<2) return 1;
    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
    // ...
}
```

Since the first entry in argv is the path to the executable, you are interested in the second argument, argv[1].

Comment: WinMain Entry Point (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 

GetCommandLine Function ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: @Trauma: true, in that case (assuming you only allow for a single command line argument), you could just use lpCmdLine instead of argv[1]. Or set the project options to use main instead of WinMain.